# Accessing tests like W3C mobileOK Checker or mobiReady from my own website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, responsive-design, w3c

This may be a long shot and I'm not looking for direct answers of code, but for pointers rather. I will appreciate any answer.

I am trying to create a website that connects to different testing tools (such as W3C MobileOk) and takes the results from them to then combine the results and release a single one.

The question is mostly about I can access the results of such checkers.

Comment: Why would you not be able to access the results? You can see the results in a browser, can't you?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".